# Ruby rails undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass when making a dropdown menu for objects in a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm making a ruby on rails app which has form partial which is rendered on the new.html.erb view. It allows users to select a category (to which a movie belongs) from a drop down menu and it looks like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @movie do |f| %>
<%= f.select :category_id, @categories %>
<%= f.input :title, label: "Movie Title" %>
<%= f.input :description %>
<%= f.input :director %>
```

And here is part of the controller for movies:

```
def new
    @movie = Movie.new
    @categories = Category.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] }
end

def create
    @movie = Movie.new(movie_params)
    @movie.category_id = params[:category_id]

    if @movie.save 
        redirect_to movie_path(@movie)
    else 
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

Now whenever a movie is created I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Movies#create undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass`
```

Apparently the error is raised on the line:
    `<%= f.select :category_id, @categories %>`

Now this worked before I deleted all the records in my entire database (the categories are all still there, however) so that might have something to do with it.
Thanks.

Comment: Include error backtrace in your question please

Comment: The issue will be that your movie is failing validation so `create` is entering the `render 'new'` branch of the `if` condition. However in `create` you're not setting `@categories`. You can fix by adding the `@categories = Category.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] }` line, the same as in `new`, or by introducing a method that sets `@categories` which is then shared by `new` and `create`.

Comment: @sapphirejones, nothing to do with the issue, but have a look at the *#pluck* method. This makes your code a lot cleaner: `Category.pluck(:name, :id)`. See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck

Comment: Please don't make more work for people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `render 'new'` in your `create` method it just call the new.html.erb (or new.* depending on template engine you are using) & not you `new action`.
So, `@categories` is getting `nil` on `new.html.erb` & hence throwing the error.

In order to get rid of the error create a private method to set categories & call it for the new & create.

```
before_action :set_categories, only: [:new, :create]

def new
  @movie = Movie.new
end

def create
  @movie = Movie.new(movie_params)
  @movie.category_id = params[:category_id]

  if @movie.save 
    redirect_to movie_path(@movie)
  else 
    render 'new'
  end
end

private
def set_categories
  @categories = Category.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] }
end
```

Comment: Or if you don't like callbacks, just make sure you set the variable `@categories` in both *#new* and *#create*.

Comment: I've tried this but also added a before_action at the top of the controller. The error isn't thrown anymore but the movie still isn't created, instead new is just rendered. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: You must have validation in your `models/movie.rb` that `category_id ` should be present. & if you try to create a movie with out any category_id it is showing an error.

Comment: Just add `<%= f.error_notification %>` under form `<%= simple_form_for(@post) do |f| %>` or similar in app/views/movies/_form.html.erb & check again

Comment: The error notification doesn't show any specific errors, and I have a migration so that each movie has a category id. I have a seperate private method called movie_params in the movies controller which states that category id must be present before creating the movie.

Comment: Another way to debug this is to temporarily replace `@movie.save` with `@movie.save!` (with an `!` at the end). This will cause an exception to be raised if the movie can't be saved. The error message from the exception should offer some clues.